# Reshape an unknown mongoDB schema

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have to work on a MongoDB database which I don't know anything about its schema. 
Using the **aggregation pipeline** is it possible to reshape the schema in `<_id,value>` pairs?

For example, suppose this is a document of your `bios` collection :

```
"_id" : 3,
"name" : {
        "first" : "Grace",
        "last" : "Hopper"
    },
"title" : "Hello World",
"birth" : ISODate("1906-12-09T05:00:00.000Z"),
"death" : ISODate("1992-01-01T05:00:00.000Z")
```

I want to reshape my schema to get:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56d420d6d4360d06e1bc5b64"),
    "document" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "_id",
            "value" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "name",
            "value" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : "first",
                    "value" : "Grace"
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "last",
                    "value" : "Hopper"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "title",
            "value" : "Hello World"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "birth",
            "value" : ISODate("1906-12-09T05:00:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "death",
            "value" : ISODate("1992-01-01T05:00:00.000Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

Keep in mind I don't know which is the schema of a MongoDB document.

Comment: you can currently do this with map-reduce only, there is a feature request to be able to do this in aggregation, but it has not been implemented yet.

Comment: Hello Asya Kamsky. Thank you for your answer. I have another question for you: I have to retrieve from an unknown schema `<nameFeld-type>` pairs. I used a map/reduce recursive function for this job. Do you know if is possible to do this with an aggregation?

Comment: Like the answer below says, if you know key names in advance then you can do it.  If you don't then you can't (yet)

Comment: Thank you, again, for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

this transformation can be done by using  aggregation framework.
As input document have a stable structure you can reshape it using [$project](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)
command.
MongoDb documents are schema-less so called dynamic schema, so you could shape them as you need.

> to project filed - just type this field as needed - to project data add cashSign $ so "name" will produce field name, but "$name" will push "name" value from input document

Please find a sample below:

```
    db.collection.aggregate( [ { 
        $project: { 
        "_id":"$_id",   
        document: [ {
                "_id" : "_id",
                "value" : "$_id"},
                {
                "_id" : "name",
                "value" : [ 
                    {
                        "_id" : "first",
                        "value" : "$first"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "_id" : "last",
                        "value" : "$last"
                    }
        ]}]
        }
        }])
```

Comment: Ok, but I don't know which is the name of each field. So I don't know which is the value of each `_id` to `project`. For example, I don't know that in my schema there is a field called name, name.first ecc...

Comment: do you have access to mongo instance to check that?

Comment: I have access to mongo instance.

Comment: so could you query it?
db._collectionName_.findOne().pretty()

Comment: I could. But mongo, as you said, is schemaless so with findOne I don't have any assurance to find all fields. What can I do using findOne?

Comment: si that means you as developer is responsible for a schema for collection (comparing to sql - you need to have certain rows, you cannot add row on- the-fly to sql DB, but you can add field to mongo document where there is a need to do so).

Comment: findOne().pretty() will display document in JSON format - so you can use it for transformation